# Adding HTTP Header to Chrome OS APP is not working

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

I want to add header `AppVersion` to my chrome os app
here what I did

```
chrome.webRequest.onHeadersReceived.addListener(
    function(details) {
      const newHeader = {name:"appVersion", value:"chrome|2.1"};
      const responseHeaders = details.responseHeaders.concat(newHeader);
      return { responseHeaders };
    },
    // filters
    {
      urls: ["https://website.link/*"],
    },
    // extraInfoSpec
    ["blocking","responseHeaders", "extraHeaders"]
    );
```

but it is not working

Comment: It's unclear whether you are creating a chrome app or a chrome extension. Chrome apps can't use webRequest API.

Comment: I’m creating chrome app, is there any way to add headers using chrome app?

Comment: Chrome apps can use webRequest inside webview, see the [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/tags/webview#type-WebRequestEventInterface).